# Setting dp in decimals in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to set the distance between 2 elements in Android. The margin I have set is 1dp and I was thinking that the distance is more than what I wanted it to be. I thought that 0.5dp would be just fine. Is it possible to set the margin in decimals as I am trying? If so, what is the minimum dp that is supported?

Comment: If you take a look at the type for the values of layout param all of them is int, especially margins.

Comment: dp means density independent pixel and a pixel is the smallest size that a screen can handle how do you think it can be of a smaller size? the smallest value you can give is 1px and it will decrease the margin in some devices as it can handle smaller sizes but on the least ppi device it will reflect the same size as of now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah, you can use 0.5dp or what ever decimal number you want, but be careful. When your dp converted to pixels they multiplied by display logic density and rounded up.

If your dp = 0.1 than for hdpi display you get (int)(0.1 * 1.5 + 0.5) = 1px. (1.5 is logical density for hdpi display)

If your dp = 0.5 that for mdpi display you get (int)(0.5 * 1 + 0.5) = 1px (1 is logical density for mdpi display)

Comment: err... I think your math is off. (int)(0.1 * 1.5 + 0.5) = (int)(0.15 + 0.5) = (int)(0.65) = 0px.

Comment: @StevenByle yours math is also off. it will be 0.75 not 0.65 ;)

Comment: @AndroidKiller You do realize in your first comment you said it was 0.75, and now you are saying it should be 0.075? Please Google "0.1 * 1.5 + 0.5" or put it in a calculator, and you will see it is 0.65...